# File diff souce code highlighting

Tags: javascript, web, syntax, editor, syntax-highlighting

various JavaScript libraries provide syntax highlighting functionality to display code on a webpage. Some example for those libraries are:

- Ace (http://ace.c9.io/) - yes, I am aware that this is a whole editor
- Prism JS (http://prismjs.com/)
- SyntaxHighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- ...and many more...

However, these editors do not support highlighting chunks of a source file. I want to enable syntax highlighting for a diff like this one: https://github.com/reviewninja/review.ninja/commit/9bd4844f0009d3471dc010d9939262f4eb2603e5 .

I could not find a library supporting the describes scenario. Does any one of you guys know of a JavaScript library describing this scenario?

Thank you very much and best Regards,

Fabian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these are inline syntax highlighting (which is what I assume you want, but some of them have side-by-side as well):

- http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/
- [jQuery Pretty Text Diff](https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff/)
- [Google Diff Match Patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)
- [jsDiffLib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) | [Demo](http://cemerick.github.io/jsdifflib/demo.html)